# ifort: command not found

Tags: bash, bashrc

I have downloaded and installed Intel Parallel_Studio_xe_2016_update1.
After that I have edited my `.bashrc` file and compiled two programs. After closing the terminal, I have tried to compile again and then I got `ifort not found`. My `.bashrc` contains:

```
PATH=/opt/intel/parallel_studio_xe_2016.1.056/compilers_and_libraries_2016/linux/bin:$PATH
export PATH
```

If I do:

```
source /opt/intel/parallel_studio_xe_2016.1.056/compilers_and_libraries_2016/linux/bin/ifortvars.sh intel64
```

I can compile fortran code. But when I close the terminal, in a new terminal compiling is not available.
What's the problem?

Comment: Where is the `ifort` command? Have you opened a new terminal after changing the PATH?

Comment: @terdon  ifrotvar.sh is located in directory where path points to.I have not changed a path.

Comment: What's `ifrotvar.sh`? You only mention `ifort` in your question. Please [edit[ and explain exactly what you did, show us the exact commands you used and the exact error message received.

Comment: @terdon ifortvars.sh is used to set environmental variables.More here http://www.bgu.ac.il/intel_fortran_docs/compiler_f/main_for/mergedProjects/bldaps_for/common/bldaps_setup_envars.htm

Answer (score 2):

You say that after you do this in the terminal, you are able to compile Fortran code:

```
source /opt/intel/parallel_studio_xe_2016.1.056/compilers_and_libraries_2016/linux/bin/ifortvars.sh intel64
```

So add it to your `.bashrc` file. After that, when you open a new terminal, you should be able to compile.